# What does the String[] do in a Query Method?

Tags: android

I have tried to find the answer for this, but it's not even documented in the official documentation.

In the `Cursor` class there are many different versions of `query()`. One of the parameters is `String[] projection` but I can't seem to figure out what this does to the method.

I have seen different examples of people using things like

`String[] projections = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };`

But I have no idea what this will do. It's never explained.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: There is no `query()` method in the [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) **interface**. Can you be more precise?

Comment: Ah you are right. I forgot the exact interface then. But Teodor already answered my questions so cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projection is which columns to return.